# have function work after div content is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with content in it. When the page loads, this function works fine. But when I update the div with content using javascript, this function fails to work.

Can anyone help me figure out what I should do to make this work?

```
$("textarea.indent").each(function(){
    var indentWidth = $(this).siblings('[class=indent]').width();
    if(indentWidth != null)
    $(this).css('text-indent', (indentWidth+5)+'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading $("textarea.indent") dynamicly?

Jquery binds all events on document ready ie. when the page loads. That means that elements added after the page is done loading won't get bound to that event. To fix this you need to dynamicly bind your events as well. Like this..

```
$.ajax{
   ...
   //Some ajax call
   success: function(){
         //Bind event
         $("textarea.indent").each(function(){
              var indentWidth = $(this).siblings('[class=indent]').width();
              if(indentWidth != null)
              $(this).css('text-indent', (indentWidth+5)+'px');
         });
   }
}
```

It doesn't have to be a ajax request thats add the elements, but my point still stands.

Comment: I thought that would be the problem.